# Align `clip-path` to image

Tags: html, css, svg

I am having some issues using an SVG clip-path. I can't work out how to make the path align with the image I am clipping - it is always way off. This is my markup:

**HTML**

```
<img class="svg-clipped" src="https://unsplash.it/1200/1200" alt="">
  <svg height="0" width="0">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="svgPath">
        <path d="M124.8,656.7H142V501.9c65.5-27.5,53.6,10.8,129,4.7v150.1h17.2v20.7H124.8V656.7z"/>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
  </svg>
```

**SCSS**

```
.svg-clipped {
 -webkit-clip-path: url(#svgPath);
 clip-path: url(#svgPath);
}
```

And a Codepen here:

https://codepen.io/mikehdesign/pen/yoOZYo

If you scroll down you will see the SVG outline I am using. Ideally I would like it to be centered on the image, though top left would be fine too. As it is I can't work out what the logic is behind the positioning.

Thanks!

Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When applying clip paths to HTML elements, it is highly recommended that you use the `objectBoundingBox` coordinate space rather than the default user space coordinates (`userSpaceOnUse`).

In `objectBoundingBox` units, the coordinates map directly to the object the clip is being applied to. So (0,0) means the top-left of the object, and (1,1) maps to the bottom-right of the object.

So if you stick to coordinates in that range, your clipping path is guaranteed to fall directly over your image.

Here's a demo with a simple diamond clip path.  I'll you to do the conversion of your shape to `objectBoundingBox` coordinates.

```css
.svg-clipped {
 -webkit-clip-path: url(#svgPath);
 clip-path: url(#svgPath);
}
```

```html
<img class="svg-clipped" src="https://unsplash.it/1200/1200" alt="">

<svg height="0" width="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="svgPath" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <path d="M 0.5,0 L 1,0.5 0.5,1, 0,0.5 Z"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Ah ok I understand - do you have any tips how I can convert / generate my SVG with `objectBoundingBox` coordinates? I am working in Illustrator but can have Sketch / Affinity Designer available too.

Comment: Actually you can. You can use a `transform` to scale the path down into the [0..1] range. https://jsfiddle.net/gk4j51mf/

Comment: The other option if you want to avoid the transform is to create something like a 100x100 artboard in Illustrator. Move your shape to it, and save as SVG. Then copy the `d` attribute from that file, but as you do, divide all the coordinates by 100.

Comment: Got it - think I will go with the second option for the simplest implementation. Thanks for taking the time to help!